# Xamarin.Forms Spreadsheet Manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, grid, spreadsheet

So far I have a Xamarin.Forms application working for Android and IOS. What I have right now is getting spreadsheets from Google Drive for user after he login with his Google Account.

What I am trying to achieve is provide an option for user to edit spreadsheet that he select. So I'm displaying a list of spreadsheets to which this account have access (from Google Drive) and then I want to load it and allow user to manipulate it (rows/cells) and save it, so to the end I have an object which represent sheet with updated values.

> Some extra information, after customer choose which spreadsheet he want to use, in code I am able to read it and what I receive is an object from type `List<List<object>>`, which represent collection with data from rows and columns.

I am not sure what framework I can use for Xamarin.Forms and loading this type of data, also to provide different functionalities similar to "mail merge".

One from the frameworks I went through was DevExpress, but this wouldn't work in my case, because of the data types I have. I prefer if framework that you suggest is free.

I was researching if it's possible to load Google Sheets on phone and allow customer to edit data, but still no information so far.

So generally what I need is a suggestion what tool/framework I can use or is it there any other approach for having same result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to say that; Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hi Stefan,
Appreciate your comment and I think you're right. The problem is that I tried to use DevExpress framework before, but still ended with unsolvable issue "https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T556033/gridcontrol-columns".
I asked here, because I expect that somebody already dealt with such matter and could suggest framework.
I understand your point, but I think even such question, could help, not only me, but other developers who in future have to deal with this.
Thanks for comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that when I get elements from Google Drive, they have property `WebViewLink`, which value is link for spreadsheet, where you can edit it. It will redirect you to online Google Spreadsheets or locally installed app (Sheets).
So now, instead of looking for framework or building my own logic, I am reusing Google Spreadsheets, which I find for much better option, for my case.